# Linux mint. Cinnamon doesn't start

Tags: linux-mint, gui

I've tried to install zsh to my Linux Mint. But after rebooting my desktop looks like this.
[image]
And I can't even to login with my user.
Please help me to return to cinnamon desktop

**upd** If I type *startx* in command line cinnamon will start